# Error occurred when trying to send rpc requests(s)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, nethereum

I am using the nethereum package in .Net and trying to invoke a smart contract with web3. Initially it was working fine, but suddenly I am getting an error while trying to get the transaction count. This is the code I am using:

```
var web3 = new Web3("https://rinkeby.infura.io/");

//getting the error from below line.
var txCount = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(DefaultAccount, Nethereum.RPC.Eth.DTOs.BlockParameter.CreatePending());
```

Error message:

```
Error occurred when trying to send rpc requests(s)
Inner exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you add the api-key also to the url? Like `https://rinkeby.infura.io/YOUR-API-KEY` ?

See also https://www.infura.io/docs/gettingStarted/makeRequests